# Need ideas of solving problem with app I built

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, mobile-development

I built this app: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.FindNewMusic_Vakil

But ios keeps rejecting me for following reason:

```
Guideline 4.2.3 - Design - Minimum Functionality


We were required to install Spotify before we could use your app. Apps should be able to run on launch, without requiring additional apps to be installed.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to ensure that users can use it upon launch. If your app requires authentication before use, please use methods that can authenticate users from within your app.
```

Even though I added another functionality which enables you to view artist in app (following pics).
Any ideas of what I should do to get app to be approved because I am lost at this point

[image: Spotify main screen]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The guideline clearly states that your app depends on other application for serving its purpose. What you're trying to do is novel but simply recommending won't suffice in my opinion. You could try providing a sample of the music and then if the user likes it, you could provide him/her with the option of redirecting to spotify. Your app should serve some purpose on its own. That's just my opinion however.